# How to hide or cover a MS Access ActiveX Web Browser control?

Tags: vba, ms-access, webbrowser-control, activex

I have a database in which users enter a value into Textbox1 on a form; the form also has an ActiveX Web Browser control (acxWebBrowser1), plus another blank Textbox2, and finally a command button.  After the user enters text into Textbox1 and clicks the command button, the VBA code will navigate to a specific web page in acxWebBrowser1, enter the Textbox1 value into the web page form, and then obtain a result in the web page in acxWebBrowser1.  The result is then grabbed by the VBA code and entered into Textbox2 on the database form.

What I need to be able to do is hide the ActiveX Web Browser control to (a) prevent the user from messing with the web page, and (b) to prevent the clutter and distraction of the ActiveX Web Browser since the VBA code does all the necessary interactions with the web page behind the scenes.

Problem is, I cannot get the acxWebBrowser1 to stay hidden behind a rectangle box control on the form because the browser automatically moves itself to the top of the stack of controls.  If I reduce the size of the acxWebBrowser1 control to be very tiny, the web page does not function properly.  If I make the web browser control not visible, then the code cannot grab the needed values.  I cannot use a POST approach to avoid using the web browser.  (I might be wrong about not being able to use POST--maybe someone can point me to how to do that if that is the way to go.)

How can I hide or put something on top of the web browser control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three hours later, it dawned on me how to accomplish hiding the ActiveX Web Browser but still get it to be accessible to the VBA code.  Simple:  Don't update the screen when running the code to access the ActiveX Web Browser and use the .Visible property to "show" the Browser Control when VBA needs to access it (but it won't be visible to the user if screen updating is off) and then hide the Browser Control when VBA is done accessing it.

Here's the code I used to accomplish that:

```
Application.Echo False  'turn off screen updating
Me.acxWebBrowser1.Visible = True  'make web browser control "visible" to VBA code

     {do stuff, like:  process web page}

Me.btnClickMe.SetFocus  'set focus on the button so we can hide the web browser control
Me.acxWebBrowser1.Visible = False  'make web browser invisible so user is not distracted
Application.Echo True  'turn screen updating back on
Me.Refresh  'refresh the screen; this is probably not necessary
```

Just be

- ***absolutely sure*** to **turn screen updating (echo) back on**

You should send any error handling to code that sets `Application.Echo True` otherwise you will not be able to see or do anything if the code crashes after setting echo to False.